# A three part puzzle

Tags: word

Take the solution of 1 and put into 2.  Take the solution of 2 and put into 3.

1. A poet probably is a professional _____.
2. Remove your's truly and replace with a tiny word... Rearrange the result for an adjective homophone that you have probably seen in a movie title.
3. Finish the nearly nonsense hang-man game:

   ```
                  ___
                 |   :
                 |   O
                 |  -|-
                 |  / 
                 |
                 |
               _____


     _ C H     _ H     _ _ _     _ _ _     _ H _
   ```

   Eliminated Letters: **<strike>S T O I U</strike>**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. A poet is probably a professional ...

> RHYMER.

2. Remove yours truly and replace with a tiny word... Rearrange the result for an adjective homophone that you have probably seen in a movie title.

> RHY(ME)R -> RHYAR -> HARRY (not sure it's an adjective homophone -- "hairy"?? but there are plenty of movies with that name in their title)

3. Finish the nearly nonsense hang-man game:  `-CH -H --- --- -H-`

> Spell it out phonetically: I guess we want ECH EH ARE ARE WHY.